# Entity listener no se ejecuta correctamente en JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Estoy teniendo problemas para que se ejecuten correctamente los listener en JPA.

El proyecto utiliza:

JPA 2.1.

EclipseLink 2.6.3

MySql 5.7.11

Tengo una entidad autor marcada con la anotación OneToMany y orphanRemoval = true hacia la entidad Libro, cuando en la entidad autor elimino la referencia a un libro y trato de actualizarla, no se está ejecutando ningun listener de la clase libro.

Añado el código para que veais de que se trata.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ges_autor")
public class Autor  implements Serializable, ItemIf {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},  fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    //@PrivateOwned he probado poniendola y tampoco funciona
    protected List<Libros> libros;

//getters y setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ges_libro")
@EntityListeners({LibroListener.class})
public class Libro implements Serializable, ItemIf {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="autor_id")
    protected Autor autor;

//getters y setters
}



public class LibroListener {
    @PrePersist
    private prePersist(Libro libro){
         System.out.println("Listener libro persist ejecutado");
    }
    @PreUpdate
    private preUpdate(Libro libro){
         System.out.println("Listener libro update ejecutado");
    }
    @PreRemove
    private preRemove(Libro libro){
        System.out.println("Listener libro remove ejecutado");
    }
}
```

Para reproducir el error basta con cargar un autor de la base de datos, eliminar un libro y hacer un merge.

```
Autor autor = getFacade().find(id);
autor.getLibros().remove(libro);
getFacade().merge(autor);
```

La anotación orphanRemoval funciona y el libro se elimina de la base de datos pero no se esta ejecutando ningún listener.

Comment: En lugar de `orphanRemoval` intenta con `Cascade`.

Comment: Puedes explicarme un poco mas, ya lo tengo marcado con cascade=CascadeType.ALL no se si te refieres a eso

Comment: Vale, sí, no lo vi. Saca `orphanRemoval` e intenta. Si no, me parece que solo se ejecutan los listeners cuando pasas la entidad en primera instancia y no como relación.

Comment: Lo he probado y si lo quito no lo elimina y añadiendo privateOwned no cambia. Por otro lado los listeners también se ejecutan cuando están como relación ya que al guardar un autor nuevo o modificar una linea se están ejecutando, el problema viene cuando se borran simplemente eliminando su referencia del autor

Comment: Una pregunta. ¿por qué mapeas `List<Libro>` en la entidad Libro si lo que debes mapear es `Autor` por ser una relación bidireccional?

Comment: Ha sido un fallo al pasar el código a la pregunta, ya lo he editado gracias. Entonces se te ocurre algo para lo del listener?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41267/discussion-between-mitsu-garcia-and-javi2ee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa del problema es un bug en la implementación de EclipseLink, según lo especificado [aqui](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events)(Gracias @Mitsu por el enlace) el método preremove debería ejecutarse tras un orphanRemoval, pero lo cierto es que no se está ejecutando. La única referencia a este bug la encontré en el [foro de eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/638733/).

No he visto que se haya comunicado el bug de manera oficial y tampoco he abierto ninguno, es el segundo bug de importancia que encuentro en EclipseLink el ultimo mes. Esto me ha hecho decidirme a empezar la titánica tarea de cambiarlo todo a Hibernate, que ya me rondaba la cabeza hace tiempo y he dejado de lado EclipseLink de una vez por todas.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Primero se hace `merge` y luego `remove`. Esto debido a que `merge` carga el contenido de la base de datos para actualizarlo (se sincroniza). Esto no es ningún bug, sino que así es como funciona *JPA*.

Entonces, si lo que deseas hacer es sólo eliminar, bastaba con:

```
Autor autor = getFacade().find(id);
autor.getLibros().remove(libro); // no es necesario merge ni commit
```

Pero si lo que deseas es actualizar algunos libros y eliminar otros, sería:

```
Autor autor = getFacade().find(id);
getFacade().merge(autor);
autor.getLibros().remove(libro);
getFacade().merge(autor);
```

Por otro lado, si hubieras hecho el `find` del usuario desde otro método en otra capa, por ejemplo, una vista, para hacer ciertas operaciones como quitar o actualizar libros, y luego llamaras a un método para actualizar, entonces sólo sería necesario el `merge`. Ya que debido a que tienes `orphanRemoval=true` en tu relación `@OneToMany`, automáticamente serían eliminados los libros que no estuvieran en la `List` o `Collection`. Es decir, sólo sería necesario:

```
getFacade().merge(autor);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no responde a la pregunta, el problema original no esta relacionado con el guardado o borrado de las entidades sino que los entity listener no se ejecutaban correctamente y era debido a un bug tal y como esta explicado en la respuesta. Un saludo